# Which personality test has a name that sounds like "Max C?"

Tags: personality, test

I was listening to a podcast about personality tests and I heard someone mention a test that phonetically sounded like it was called "Max C." Looking this up yields no answers. I've also tried a few similar-sounding words, but no dice. Does anyone know of which test this is and what its *actual* name is?

Comment: Can you link to the podcast?

Comment: [Minnesota Multiphasic Personality Inventory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minnesota_Multiphasic_Personality_Inventory) (MMPI)<br>
[Millon Clinical Multiaxial Inventory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Millon_Clinical_Multiaxial_Inventory) (MCMI)<br> This are only tests I know of (except for MBTI) that start with letter M. Podcast link could help.

Comment: @Fizz Unfortunately, it's behind a paywall.

Comment: @GogaVachnadze Thanks for the info. I appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

Could be "[maximum] Conscientiousness," one of the core traits in the Big Five [personality index]. The Big Five traits are the best-known personality models in modern academic psychology, and frequently referred to by their initials (O C E A N).

> https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conscientiousness

Comment: Thanks, maybe this person was referring to the Big Five test, although I'm not 100% sure.